# Defining objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I want to define the following object in javascript:

```
var property = 'foo';
var value = 'bar';
var obj = {
    property: value;
};
```

This will result the following:

```
obj.property <-> 'bar';
obj.foo <-> undefined
```

This is normal, but how to define the object to get:

```
obj.foo = 'bar';
```

Possible solution is:

```
var obj = {};
obj[property] = value;
```

or

```
var obj = new Object();
obj[property] = value;
```

But this is not convient when have to define objects like:

```
var obj = {
    o1: {
        oo1: {
            property: value;
        }
    }
};
```

Again, what I want is:

```
var property = 'foo';
var value = 'bar';
var obj = {
    property: value;
}; 
alert(obj.foo); // I want this to alert: 'bar'
```

How you handle similar situations?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to use variables from the global scope in your object's constructor several levels deep. Apart from that being, well, risky to put it politely, since there it isn't really possible to be sure about the value of these variables, you could specify the scope like so:

```
var property = 'foo';
var value = 'bar';
var obj = {val : window.value};//doesn't work for property id's
var obj[window.property] = obj.val;
alert(obj.foo);//alerts 'bar'
```

Alternatively, make your constructor accept parameters:

```
function Foobar(prop,val)
{
    this[prop] = val;
}
var obj = new Foobar('foo','bar');
alert(obj.foo);//alerts 'bar'
```

In my second example, nested objects can use the arguments passed to their 'parent'/containing object like this:

```
function Foobar(prop,val)
{
    Foobar.prop = prop;
    Foobar.val = val;
    ...
    this.subObj = {};
    this.subObj[Foobar.prop] = Foobar.val;//var prop from scope Foobar, same as window
}
```

Taking advantage of the fact that variables of functions or objects can be made static, you might even do something like this:

```
Foobar.prop = (typeof Foobar.prop !== 'undefined' ? Foobar.prop : prop);
//or
Foobar.subObj=  {new Foobar};//extending parent object
Foobar.subObj.newProp = 'newVal';
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this in JavaScript is to use the brackets:

```
var property = 'foo',
    value = 'bar',
    obj = {};

obj[property] = value;
```

I'm not sure I understand why this is impractical for you. Could you expound on that a bit?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want an alias.

If I understand correctly, you want to do this:

```
var obj = {something: 'bar'};
alert(obj.foo); // alerts 'bar'
```

To do this, define a getter. This is simplest with a prototype:

```
function Factory() {
}
Factory.prototype = {
    get foo() {
        return this.something;
    }
};

var obj = new Factory;
obj.something = 'bar';
alert(obj.foo); // alerts 'bar'
```

The prototype is basically the model for the object. When you create a new Factory, the resultant object has the getter 'something' that returns the value of foo.  This is kind of messy syntax, but it works for what you want.

Also, you could avoid the prototype entirely and do this:

```
var obj = {};
obj.__defineGetter__('foo', function () { return this.something; });
obj.something = 'bar';
alert(obj.foo); // alerts 'bar'
```

The same can be done with `__defineSetter`. This is ES5 syntax and doesn't work in all browsers (IE), but should work in newer browsers.

See [John Resig's blog](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend https://github.com/leecrossley/dotject

You can make objects with:

```
dotject("a,b.c");
```

Makes:

```
{
  "a": {},
  "b": {
    "c": {}
  }
}
```

Or a more real world example:

```
var camera = {isEnabled: true};
camera = dotject("settings.encoding.format,output.data.base64", camera, "JPEG", true);

{
  "isEnabled": true,
  "settings": {
    "encoding": {
      "format": "JPEG"
    }
  },
  "output": {
    "data": {
      "base64": true
    }
  }
}
```